# Python list with constant value

Tags: python, arrays, list, code-formatting

I really love pythons possibility to shorten things up with its shorthand for loops — but sometimes, I need to obtain a list containing one value multiple times, which I did the following way:

```
plot(seconds, [z0 for s in seconds], '--')
```

But that unused `s` really disturbs me for aesthetic reasons.

Is there any shorter (and more beautiful) way of doing so? Like some special “multiplication” of some value?

Comment: You can multiply lists: `[1] * 3 -> [1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: the usual name for unused variables is `_`, unless you can get rid of it

Comment: although sometimes `_` is for localizing strings... and other times it is a autopopulated context variable provided by the python shell ...

Comment: @njzk2 and @Joran: I've always seen double-underscore `__` used as a "junk" variable, specifically to avoid clashing with other uses of single-underscore `_`, like the interactive interpreter and the [`gettext` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.install).  As a bonus, while the leading underscore makes it invisible to `from <module> import *`, it's not quite long enough to trigger [class-private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You mean like:

```
[z0] * len(seconds)
```

Comment: I had no clue this was a thing... Time to hit the basics

Comment: @AdamHughes As Joran Beasley said in his answer, the list is several references to the same object. So if the object can be mutated (like a list or dict), then the changes to one element be reflected for every other element (as they are the same object). However, this is safe if the object is immutable (such as strings or numbers, or a tuple).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I wouldn't have realized that at all.

Comment: wow! who woulda thought.

Answer (score 8):

depending on what z0 is

```
 [z0]*len(seconds)
```

fair warning this will not work like you hope in the case that z0 is a mutable datatype

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the way you are doing it is not that dirty...  But the `numpy.fill` function is a bit more tidy:

```
In [4]: import numpy as np
In [5]: x=np.empty(5)

In [6]: x.fill(8)

In [7]: x
Out[7]: array([ 8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.])
```